# Why are Fluent UI react and Fluent UI web components libraries different?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

Not sure it's the right question for this forum, but I couldn't find another place for it.

Our design team built their design system based on fluent ui libraries as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web). They downloaded the design from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/resources).

Unfortunately, our engineering team is using Angular, so we naturally reached for the option of web [component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/) but found out to our surprise that the library is completely different - different set of components, abilities, and of course - a completely different design.

I thought that all fluentui platforms are supposed to be an implementation / interface of the same design. Why is this not the case? What am I missing?

Is there a way we can use the design described in [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/resources) in Angular? (Except actually using the react library inside my Angular project).

Thanks for helping and very sorry if this question is inappropriate for this forum.

Comment: Just had the same problem today, Microsoft aren't really good at naming things and it is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

fluent web components integrated with angular.

take a look at [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/angular)

Comment: I saw this article. This just explains how to use the web components in Angular, it's not an "Angular" solution. And even if it was - it doesn't answer my question. My problem was that our design team built their design based on the react component which look different.